# Cross-correlation seems defined backwards

Tags: terminology, cross-correlation

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are real. Why

$$
C(\tau)=(f\star g)(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) g(t + \tau)dt \tag{1}
$$

and not

$$
C(\tau)=(f\star g)(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) g(t - \tau)dt\tag{2}
$$

where $f=$ input, $g =$ template/pattern to be matched. $(2)$ properties:

1. If $g$ is centered at $t=0$, and $f$ is $g$ shifted to $T$, then $C$ peaks at $T$.
2. If $g$ is centered at $t=T_0$, and $f$ is $g$ shifted to $T_1$, then $C$ peaks at $T_1 - T_0$.

   - Suppose $f$ is $g$ shifted to $t=0$. Then, $C$ peaks at $-T_0$, meaning $g$ is most similar to $f$ when shifted left by $T_0$.

$(1)$ has all of this backwards. $C$ at $1$ is similarity of $g$ with $f$ at $-1$, i.e. inner product of $f$ with $g$ shifted to $-1$.

How is this useful? Why not just have $C(1)$ mean "similarity of input with template shifted by $1$", which for template centered at 0 is nicely "template centered at $1$", e.g.

> $C$ peaks at (1cm, 2cm) because that's where the apple is in the image

Yes, $(1)$ becomes $(2)$ if we look at it as matching *input* against template instead, but this answers the reverse of "where at input does this sub-pattern occur". I can also see it as answering "after how long will input match template if we pass it through the template (e.g. signal into system)", but we won't ask this for images and it's more suited as a physics than statistical tool.

Whatever the case, does $(2)$ have a name?

Comment: Cross-posted from [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/82446/50076).

Comment: Re "How is this useful?" The one formula is simply converted to the other by negating $\tau,$ so if one is useful, *a fortiori* so is the other.

Comment: @whuber I think a good question here is why is it predominantly given in the form the OP gave? What was the reasoning behind that convention or was it simply a coin toss?

Comment: @Dan Agreed.  There are different conventions in different communities, but generally (1) is known as a cross-correlation and (2) is related to a *convolution.*  There's nothing inherently "backwards" about (1), though: a step forward in time for $g$ is identical to a step backwards in time for $f,$ so the only thing under discussion concerns the order in which $f$ and $g$ are mentioned in the notation.

Comment: @whuber look carefully at the variables- (2) is NOT convolution. Convolution requires time reversal for the unit under the integral which is not happening in this case.

Comment: @Dan I am aware of that: that's why I said "is related to."  I didn't want to go into the time reversal nicety, because it isn't relevant to the points I was making.

Comment: @whuber Strange seeing an ML-er not think (1) is backwards. Is there any implementation or visual of CNNs (actually cross-corr nets) which slides the _input_ against the kernel? Do we eat by fixing hands and moving the rest of the body?

Comment: You seem to struggling with some kind of intuition rather than with the mathematical concept.  To that end, it would help to have some descriptions or definitions concerning how you conceive "input," "template/pattern," "kernel," and "matching."

Comment: @whuber I'm not confused, I'm questioning the convention.

Comment: I'm not trying to suggest you're confused.  I'm saying that we are more likely to make some progress in understanding and resolving this situation once you tell us what you really mean by these terms.  Until then it looks likely that a shared understanding and accurate communication might be difficult to achieve.

Comment: @whuber Okay, sure. "template" = apple. "input" = fruits portrait. "output" = (x, y) coordinates of apple on image. If the image is 400x400 and the apple is at pixel 50 down and 100 right, cross-correlation outputs (-50, -100). -- This disagrees with 1) implementation, and 2) intuitive conceptualization, where in both the _template_ slides against the _input_, not the other way around. The natural answer here to "where is peak similarity" is (50, 100).

Answer (score 0):

If the interpretation of **$\tau$** is **correlation lag** , then use the form of equation given by (1). Which is,

$$C(\tau)=(f\star g)(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^*(t) g(t + \tau)dt $$

Details in this [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83018/40239)